# Rails variable returns two different values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

For some weird reason an instance variable I have puts out two different values on two different occasions.

```
$ puts @project.to_yaml
```

gives:

```
  id: 3
  title: '123'
  created_at: 2014-04-07 23:54:18.253262000 Z
  updated_at: 2014-04-09 09:20:33.847246000 Z
  amount_donated: 50000
```

and

```
$ @project.amount_donated
```

gives:

```
  nil
```

Explain this one to me because I'm terribly lost.

**EDIT**
Project model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'date'

  attr_accessor(:amount_donated)
  before_save :convert_params

  def convert_params
    if amount_donated.present?
      value = amount_donated.to_s.split(',').join
      value = value.to_f * 100
      update_column(:amount_donated, value.to_i)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: whats is @project? could you please add the Project.rb source code (if it is a model, as I'm guessing)

Comment: why there is `,` at the end of `attr_accessor` ?

Comment: copy and paste error there one one thing that was behind it that doesn't matter pdf. i'll remove that from the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update_column(:amount_donated, value.to_i)` shows that you have a column `amount_donated`, but `attr_accessor :amount_donated` shows that you have a virtual attribute. So which one is it?

I'd suggest removing `attr_accessor :amount_donated`

**edit:**

The `attr_accessor :amount_donated` does something like this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'date'

  before_save :convert_params

  def amound_donated
    @amount_donated
  end

  def amound_donated=(value)
    @amount_donated = value
  end

  def convert_params
    if amount_donated.present?
      value = amount_donated.to_s.split(',').join
      value = value.to_f * 100
      update_column(:amount_donated, value.to_i)
    end
  end
end
```

Thus when you accessed `@project.amount_donated` you were actually accessing the getter method `amount_donated` not the column (ActiveRecord getter).

Seems that `to_yaml` saw the column instead of the ActiveRecord's getter.

Comment: `attr_accessor` creates new getter and setter methods, overwriting AciveRecord's default getters and setters

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might be you are using cached copy of `@project`

```
@project.reload.amount_donated
```